# Multiple Jquery fade images on the same XHTML page

Tags: jquery, html, image, fadein, fade

Using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) to fade in & out a series of [png](/questions/tagged/png) images on my page.  It works great (code below)!  However I would like to create a second set of completely different fading images inside a new table cell on the same page, and am having trouble getting both to function at once.  I figure it's something simple but I am a new coder and have tried several options to no avail.  My successful code for the single set of fading images is as follows... what would I need to recreate something similar inside a table cell?

```js
$(function(){
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){$('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 4000);
});
```

```css
.fadein { position:absolute; left:5; top:0; }
.fadein img { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; }
    
.fadelinks, .faderandom { position:absolute; }
.fadelinks > *, .faderandom > * { position:absolute; }
    
.multipleslides { position:relative; height:563px; width:550px; float:left; }
.multipleslides > * { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; display:block; }
```

```html
<head>
    <img src="map.png" width="1334" height="786" border="0" usemap="#Map" />
    <map name="Map" id="Map">
      <area shape="poly" coords="80,604,94,654,300,599,286,550" href="doit.html" />
      <area shape="poly" coords="60,535,76,590,347,516,335,461" href="http://WhiteboardCreative.net/" />
      <area shape="poly" coords="43,460,57,519,401,429,384,368" href="whoweart.html" />
    </map>
    
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
    
    <div class="fadein"; align="left">
      <img src="notes active/notes1.png" />
      <img src="notes active/notes4.png" />
      <img src="notes active/notes3.png" />
      <img src="notes active/notes2.png" />
      <img src="notes active/notes5.png" />
      <img src="notes active/notes7.png" />
      <img src="notes active/notes8.png" />
      <img src="notes active/notes9.png" />
      <img src="notes active/notes10.png" /></div>
    </div>
    <h2>
</body>
```

Comment: P.S: you have extra `</div><h2>` in your document (probably a copy/paste typo?)

Answer (score 0):

Simply target `.each()` set of your wrapper `.fadein` parents:

```
$(".fadein").each(function(){
    // Now use `$(this)` to reference to the .fadein
    $(this).find('img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
        $(this).find('img:first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo( this );
    }, 4000);
});
```